# How to get client data without having client login

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-authentication

### Situation

Using the Google Core Reporting API (v3), I need to get client companies analytics and other data but since they are organizations and not individuals, It is too tedious to put them through the login flow in order to get access tokens.

I know that I can obtain a token for such a request using the [Server to Server auth process](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), but that involves obtaining and holding on to their private key which then grants me, to my knowledge, near unlimited access.

### Question

Is the Server to Server method the only way to do this or is there something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, server to server is the only method which doesn't require the client login (`OAuth`).**

Remarks about Google APIs:

- Server-to-server comes in 2 flavours: `Service account` and `API key`
- The vast majority of Google APIs (including Google Analytics APIs) only support the `Service account` method for server-to-server access
- Some (eg [Google Search Console](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/how-tos/authorizing#APIKey)) support `API keys` instead of `Service account`
- You could use `OAuth` and store refresh tokens so people don't have to authenticate every time should you want to use a method that requires client login

Remarks about GA:

- You should use the [v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) reporting API as [v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) is being discontinued